# Request for [blue-eyes] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

The Blue Eyes puzzle has become increasingly popular with loads of questions based on in it. Some ask for explanations, while others are variants.

Since I don't have the time, could someone please create a tag and tag all the related questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Done!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blue-eyes) [blue-eyes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blue-eyes)

Mods: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), please.